# Multithreaded Client/Server

Tags: c, multithreading

**EDIT: [I have made some thread specific modifications, though still getting the same error]   Please HELP**

I'm writing a multi-threaded file transfer client/server as part of an assignment.My server works fine and sends the files back, if client is single-threaded. But, as soon as I start a multi-threaded client, server crashes.

**some implementation logic** 
In server there's a call-back function that's called whenever a request lands on server. It takes request context, file path, and a void * argument as parameters. I bundle this request into a structure(both path and context) and insert in a queue. Threads dequeue these requests from the worker functions and serve them to the client.

Below is the relevant code:

main.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#include "gfserver.h"
#include "content.h"

#define USAGE                                                                 \
"usage:\n"                                                                    \
"  webproxy [options]\n"                                                      \
"options:\n"                                                                  \
"  -p                  Listen port (Default: 8888)\n"                         \
"  -t                  Number of threads (default:1)"                         \
"  -c                  Content file mapping keys to content files\n"          \
"  -h                  Show this help message\n"





//extern ssize_t handler_get(gfcontext_t *ctx, char *path, void* arg);
extern ssize_t enqueueContext(gfcontext_t *ctx, char *path, void* arg);
extern void initThreads(int n_thread);
extern void destroyThreads();
/* Main ========================================================= */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int option_char = 0;
  unsigned short port = 8888;
  int num_threads = 1;
  char *content = "content.txt";
  gfserver_t *gfs;

  // Parse and set command line arguments
  while ((option_char = getopt(argc, argv, "p:t:c:h")) != -1) {
    switch (option_char) {
      case 'p': // listen-port
        port = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      case 't':
        num_threads = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      case 'c': // file-path
        content = optarg;
        break;
      case 'h': // help
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", USAGE);
        exit(0);
        break;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", USAGE);
        exit(1);
    }
  }

    /*allocate memory for the contexts*/
  content_init(content);

  /*Initializing server*/
  gfs = gfserver_create();

  /*Setting options*/
  gfserver_set_port(gfs, port);
  gfserver_set_maxpending(gfs, 100);

  gfserver_set_handler(gfs, enqueueContext);
  gfserver_set_handlerarg(gfs, NULL);

  initThreads(num_threads);

  /*Loops forever*/
  gfserver_serve(gfs);

  destroyThreads();

}
```

handler.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "gfserver.h"
#include "content.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define MAX_QUEUE   500


struct context_handler{
    gfcontext_t *hctx;
    char hpath[512];
};

typedef struct context_handler context_handler;

/*Queue implementation starts here*/
context_handler *queue_array[MAX_QUEUE];

pthread_mutex_t mutexrear;
pthread_mutex_t mutexfront;
pthread_mutex_t mutexcontext;

pthread_mutex_t empty_mutex;
pthread_cond_t empty_mutex_cv;

int rear = - 1;
int front = - 1;
int req_count = 0;

int empty();

int isEmpty()
{
    int rv;
    rv = empty();
    return rv;
}

int empty()
{
    if (front == - 1 || front > rear){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }


}

void enqueue(context_handler *item)
{
    if (rear == MAX_QUEUE - 1)
        printf("Queue Overflow \n");
    else
    {
        if (front == - 1)
        {
            front = 0;
        }

        rear = rear + 1;
//        req_count++;
        queue_array[rear] = item;
//        printf("Enqueued.\n");
    }
} /*End of insert()*/

context_handler * dequeue()
{
    context_handler *ch;

    if (front == - 1 || front > rear)
    {
        printf("Queue Underflow \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        ch = queue_array[front];
        front++;
        front %= MAX_QUEUE;
//        req_count--;
        return ch;
    }
}

/*Queue implementation ends here*/

int total_threads=0;
int active_threads=0;
context_handler *ch=NULL;


void *handler_get(void *hp);

void initThreads(int n_threads)
{
    total_threads = n_threads;
    pthread_t threads[total_threads];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexrear, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexfront, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexfront, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&empty_mutex_cv, NULL);

    int rc;
    long t;
    for(t=0; t<total_threads; t++){

        printf("In connection handler: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, handler_get, (void *)&t);
        if (rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }


}

void destroyThreads()
{
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexrear);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexfront);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexcontext);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&empty_mutex_cv);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

ssize_t enqueueContext(gfcontext_t *ctx, char *path, void* arg)
{

    context_handler ch;

    ch.hctx = ctx;

    strcpy(ch.hpath, path);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexfront);
    enqueue(&ch);
    pthread_cond_signal(&empty_mutex_cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexfront);


    return 0;
}

void *handler_get(void *thread_id){

    long tid;
    tid = (long) thread_id;

    while(1)
    {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexcontext);
        while(isEmpty())
           pthread_cond_wait(&empty_mutex_cv, &mutexcontext);
        context_handler *ch = dequeue();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexcontext);


        char *path = ch->hpath;

         gfcontext_t *ctx= ch->hctx;

        printf("Path: %s ThreadID:%ld\n", path, tid);

        int fildes;
        size_t file_len, bytes_transferred;
        ssize_t read_len, write_len;
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        if( 0 > (fildes = content_get(path)))
            return gfs_sendheader(ctx, GF_FILE_NOT_FOUND, 0);

        /* Calculating the file size */
        file_len = lseek(fildes, 0, SEEK_END);

        gfs_sendheader(ctx, GF_OK, file_len);

        /* Sending the file contents chunk by chunk. */
        bytes_transferred = 0;
        while(bytes_transferred < file_len){
            read_len = pread(fildes, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, bytes_transferred);
            if (read_len <= 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "handle_with_file read error, %zd, %zu, %zu", read_len, bytes_transferred, file_len );
                gfs_abort(ctx);
                return -1;
            }
            write_len = gfs_send(ctx, buffer, read_len);
            if (write_len != read_len){
                fprintf(stderr, "handle_with_file write error");
                gfs_abort(ctx);
                return -1;
            }
            bytes_transferred += write_len;

        }

//          return (void *)bytes_transferred;

    }

}
```

Log

```
The server process seems to have crashed.
The server exited with returncode --6
The client exited with returncode --6
*****
client output:
recv: connection reset
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa4000008c0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa41c0008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa4080008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa4140008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa4040008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3f40008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3f80008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa4100008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3f00008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3e40008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3fc0008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa40c0008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3e80008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa3ec0008c0 ***
recv: connection reset
*** glibc detected *** ./gfclient_download: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fa4180008c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7de16)[0x7fa42a570e16]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7fa42a560a95]
./gfclient_download[0x4022b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7fa42a8b9e9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa42a5e68bd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 00:13 737624                             /tmp/vmuser_tmgdmwtnqr/gfclient_download
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 00:13 737624                             /tmp/vmuser_tmgdmwtnqr/gfclient_download
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 00:13 737624                             /tmp/vmuser_tmgdmwtnqr/gfclient_download
01293000-012b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fa3e4000000-7fa3e4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3e4021000-7fa3e8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3e8000000-7fa3e8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3e8021000-7fa3ec000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3ec000000-7fa3ec021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3ec021000-7fa3f0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f0000000-7fa3f0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f0021000-7fa3f4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f4000000-7fa3f4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f4021000-7fa3f8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f8000000-7fa3f8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3f8021000-7fa3fc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3fc000000-7fa3fc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa3fc021000-7fa400000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa400000000-7fa400021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa400021000-7fa404000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa404000000-7fa404021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa404021000-7fa408000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa408000000-7fa408021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa408021000-7fa40c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa40c000000-7fa40c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa40c021000-7fa410000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa410000000-7fa410021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa410021000-7fa414000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa414000000-7fa414021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa414021000-7fa418000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa418000000-7fa418021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa418021000-7fa41c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa41c000000-7fa41c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa41c021000-7fa420000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4220c0000-7fa4220d5000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa4220d5000-7fa4222d4000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa4222d4000-7fa4222d5000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa4222d5000-7fa4222d6000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa4222d6000-7fa4222e2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400512                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fa4222e2000-7fa4224e1000 ---p 0000c000 ca:01 400512                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fa4224e1000-7fa4224e2000 r--p 0000b000 ca:01 400512                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fa4224e2000-7fa4224e3000 rw-p 0000c000 ca:01 400512                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fa4224e3000-7fa4224e4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4224e4000-7fa422ce4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa422ce4000-7fa422ce5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa422ce5000-7fa4234e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4234e5000-7fa4234e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4234e6000-7fa423ce6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa423ce6000-7fa423ce7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa423ce7000-7fa4244e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4244e7000-7fa4244e8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4244e8000-7fa424ce8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa424ce8000-7fa424ce9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa424ce9000-7fa4254e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4254e9000-7fa4254ea000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4254ea000-7fa425cea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa425cea000-7fa425ceb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa425ceb000-7fa4264eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4264eb000-7fa4264ec000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4264ec000-7fa426cec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa426cec000-7fa426ced000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa426ced000-7fa4274ed000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4274ed000-7fa4274ee000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4274ee000-7fa427cee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa427cee000-7fa427cef000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa427cef000-7fa4284ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4284ef000-7fa4284f0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4284f0000-7fa428cf0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa428cf0000-7fa428cf1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa428cf1000-7fa4294f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4294f1000-7fa4294f2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa4294f2000-7fa429cf2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa429cf2000-7fa429cf3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa429cf3000-7fa42a4f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa42a4f3000-7fa42a6a7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fa42a6a7000-7fa42a8a7000 ---p 001b4000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fa42a8a7000-7fa42a8ab000 r--p 001b4000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fa42a8ab000-7fa42a8ad000 rw-p 001b8000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fa42a8ad000-7fa42a8b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa42a8b2000-7fa42a8ca000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7fa42a8ca000-7fa42aac9000 ---p 00018000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7fa42aac9000-7fa42aaca000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7fa42aaca000-7fa42aacb000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7fa42aacb000-7fa42aacf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa42aacf000-7fa42aaf1000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400518                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fa42acdb000-7fa42acde000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa42acec000-7fa42aced000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa42acee000-7fa42acf1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa42acf1000-7fa42acf2000 r--p 00022000 ca:01 400518                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fa42acf2000-7fa42acf4000 rw-p 00023000 ca:01 400518                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff7de8a000-7fff7deab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff7ded4000-7fff7ded5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
gfc_perform returned an error -4
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7de16)[0x7fa42a570e16]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7fa42a560a95]
./gfclient_download[0x4022b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7fa42a8b9e9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa42a5e68bd]
======= Memory map: ========
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7de16)[0x7fa42a570e16]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7fa42a560a95]
./gfclient_download[0x4022b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7fa42a8b9e9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa42a5e68bd]
======= Memory map: ========
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7de16)[0x7fa42a570e16]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7fa42a560a95]
./gfclient_download[0x4022b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7fa42a8b9e9a]
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa42a5e68bd]
======= Memory map: ========
======= Backtrace: =========
======= Backtrace: =========
.6(+0x7de16)[0x7fa42a570e16]
*****
server output:
listening locally for connections on port 8888
_close:: Connection reset by peer
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./bvtgfserver_main: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000024281f0 ***
_gf_send: Bad file descriptor
gfs_send failed
handle_with_file write error======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7de16)[0x7f5fa5146e16]
./bvtgfserver_main[0x401902]
./bvtgfserver_main[0x402268]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7f5fa548fe9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f5fa51bc8bd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 00:13 738305                             /tmp/vmuser_tmgdmwtnqr/bvtgfserver_main
00604000-00605000 r--p 00004000 00:13 738305                             /tmp/vmuser_tmgdmwtnqr/bvtgfserver_main
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 00:13 738305                             /tmp/vmuser_tmgdmwtnqr/bvtgfserver_main
00606000-00607000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02423000-02445000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f5f98000000-7f5f98021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f98021000-7f5f9c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9cea2000-7f5f9ceb7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5f9ceb7000-7f5f9d0b6000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5f9d0b6000-7f5f9d0b7000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5f9d0b7000-7f5f9d0b8000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 395315                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5f9d0b8000-7f5f9d0b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9d0b9000-7f5f9d0ba000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9d0ba000-7f5f9d8ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9d8ba000-7f5f9d8bb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9d8bb000-7f5f9e0bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9e0bb000-7f5f9e0bc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9e0bc000-7f5f9e8bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9e8bc000-7f5f9e8bd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9e8bd000-7f5f9f0bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9f0bd000-7f5f9f0be000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9f0be000-7f5f9f8be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9f8be000-7f5f9f8bf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5f9f8bf000-7f5fa00bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa00bf000-7f5fa00c0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa00c0000-7f5fa08c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa08c0000-7f5fa08c1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa08c1000-7f5fa10c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa10c1000-7f5fa10c2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa10c2000-7f5fa18c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa18c2000-7f5fa18c3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa18c3000-7f5fa20c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa20c3000-7f5fa20c4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa20c4000-7f5fa28c4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa28c4000-7f5fa28c5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa28c5000-7f5fa30c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa30c5000-7f5fa30c6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa30c6000-7f5fa38c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa38c6000-7f5fa38c7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa38c7000-7f5fa40c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa40c7000-7f5fa40c8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa40c8000-7f5fa48c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa48c8000-7f5fa48c9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa48c9000-7f5fa50c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa50c9000-7f5fa527d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f5fa527d000-7f5fa547d000 ---p 001b4000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f5fa547d000-7f5fa5481000 r--p 001b4000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f5fa5481000-7f5fa5483000 rw-p 001b8000 ca:01 400509                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f5fa5483000-7f5fa5488000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa5488000-7f5fa54a0000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f5fa54a0000-7f5fa569f000 ---p 00018000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f5fa569f000-7f5fa56a0000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f5fa56a0000-7f5fa56a1000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 400510                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f5fa56a1000-7f5fa56a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa56a5000-7f5fa56c7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 400518                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f5fa58b1000-7f5fa58b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa58b5000-7f5fa58c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5fa58c7000-7f5fa58c8000 r--p 00022000 ca:01 400518                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f5fa58c8000-7f5fa58ca000 rw-p 00023000 ca:01 400518                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff631e2000-7fff63203000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff6321b000-7fff6321c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
In connection handler: creating thread 0
In connection handler: creating thread 1
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 2
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 3
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 4
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 5
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 6
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 7
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 8
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 9
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 10
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 11
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 12
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 13
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 14
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
In connection handler: creating thread 15
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
Queue Underflow 
Enqueued Items: 0
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Enqueued.
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
Path: /junk/file000.txt ThreadID:140734856436816
```

Comment: run it under gdb and post the back trace

Comment: *The server crashes* is a little too vague - crashes how? segfault? Also, you're not handling multithreading properly. You are reading the values of various shared variables without synchronizing access. You can't just read `front` without locking, since other threads may be in the middle of modifying it. The code has race conditions all over the place.

Comment: backtrace given above. Sorry, I missed that. And, only boss enqueues the request. do you think I should still lock front?

Comment: Until you know otherwise, lock everything.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, can I lock 'dequeue' and if I do that would it mean that I have locked the whole method? Also, can I lock a condition like this:         
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexfront);
    if (front == - 1 || front > rear)
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexfront);

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves can you please point me specifically towards race conditions and how I can avoid them in code? I understand what you are saying but can't recognize how and where in code I can fix that.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the goal is here or if a circular queue is appropriate, since multiple client threads could be returning items back to the free pool queue out or order. In this case, single linked list fifo queues would be more appropriate, since this would allow items to be returned or added out of original order.

Comment: do you see it helping with the crash? My immediate concern is to somehow see the program running :)

Comment: Thanks guys. There were thread issues in the program, which I have been able to sort out somewhat, but basically it was crashing because of a memory issue than anything else. I wasn't allocating memory to a structure. It's working now.